# PostgreSQL aggregate function for integer data

Tags: postgresql, integer, aggregate

Obviously, `string_agg` is not working, because I have integer data to aggregate.
What would be the equivalent function for integrer data:

```
SELECT the_geom, 
       string_agg(profile_id || ', ' || upper_dept, || ', ' ||lower_dept, || ', ' ||phaq_val_1, '; ' ORDER BY upper_dept) AS pH_info
FROM ph_agua_1 
GROUP BY the_geom
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Comment: I expect retrieving info from my table where I can see from each centroid (different rows have same centoid(the_geom) a kind of concatenated fields. Kind of summarizing certains fields, one after the other

Answer (score 1):

You can convent int to string with operator `::` like this:

```
SELECT the_geom, 
       string_agg(profile_id::text || ', ' || upper_dept::text, || ', ' ||lower_dept::text, || ', ' ||phaq_val_1::text, '; ' ORDER BY upper_dept) AS pH_info
FROM ph_agua_1 
GROUP BY the_geom
```

Comment: I solved my question with:
SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG (
        profile_id || ' ' || upper_dept || ' ' || lower_dept  || ' ' || phaq_val_1
        ORDER BY
            upper_dept
    ) the_geom
FROM
    ph_agua_1 
GROUP BY
    the_geom

@I hope this helps to get out of my question ban